# How to make a ternary diagram with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How do I draw a ternary diagram using gnuplot? It doesn't seem to support this type of plot natively.

Answer (score 1):

I used https://staff.aist.go.jp/a.noda/programs/ternary/ternary-en.html as the basis for this template. I prefer to get the coordinates for my diagram using Excel and saving them on a file. I like to use Sans Fira as the font for my diagrams, but I used Arial as a universally available font. Here's the script used

```
set bmargin 3
set lmargin 3
set rmargin 3
set tmargin 3
set size ratio 0.866
set yrange [0:0.866]
set xrange [0:1]
set noborder
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset key
set tmargin 5
set title "Ternary diagram template" font "Arial, 14" offset 0, 1

#~Red
C1 = '#FE5F55'
#~Blue
C2 = '#5E52FE'
#~Green
C3 = '#0CCE6B'


set label 'x' at 0.5, 0.9 center textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 12"
set label 'y' at -0.02, -0.03 center textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 12"
set label 'z' at 1.02, -0.03 center textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 12"

#Grid lines
set style line 1 lc rgb C1 lt 1 lw 2 pt -1 ps 1
set style line 10 lc rgb C1 lt 0 lw 1.5 pt -1 ps 1
set style line 2 lc rgb C2 lt 1 lw 2 pt -1 ps 1
set style line 20 lc rgb C2 lt 0 lw 1.5 pt -1 ps 1
set style line 3 lc rgb C3 lt 1 lw 2 pt -1 ps 1
set style line 30 lc rgb C3 lt 0 lw 1.5 pt -1 ps 1

# x
set arrow 1 from 0,0 to 1, 0.0 nohead linestyle 1
set arrow 2 from 0.97, 0.0866 to 0.05, 0.0866 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 3 from 0.92, 0.1732 to 0.10, 0.173 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 4 from 0.87, 0.2598 to 0.15, 0.260 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 5 from 0.82, 0.3464 to 0.20, 0.346 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 6 from 0.77, 0.4330 to 0.25, 0.433 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 7 from 0.72, 0.5196 to 0.30, 0.520 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 8 from 0.67, 0.6062 to 0.35, 0.606 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 9 from 0.62, 0.6928 to 0.40, 0.693 nohead linestyle 10
set arrow 10 from 0.57, 0.7794 to 0.45, 0.779 nohead linestyle 10

set label '0.1' at 0.99, 0.0866 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.2' at 0.94, 0.1732 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.3' at 0.89, 0.2598 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.4' at 0.84, 0.3464 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.5' at 0.79, 0.4330 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.6' at 0.74, 0.5196 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.7' at 0.69, 0.6062 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.8' at 0.64, 0.6928 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"
set label '0.9' at 0.59, 0.7794 textcolor rgb C1 font "Arial, 9"

# z
set arrow 11 from 1, 0 to 0.50, 0.866 nohead linestyle 2
set arrow 12 from 0.04, 0.1039 to 0.1,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 13 from 0.09, 0.1905 to 0.2,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 14 from 0.14, 0.2771 to 0.3,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 15 from 0.19, 0.3637 to 0.4,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 16 from 0.24, 0.4503 to 0.5,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 17 from 0.29, 0.5369 to 0.6,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 18 from 0.34, 0.6235 to 0.7,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 19 from 0.39, 0.7101 to 0.8,0 nohead linestyle 20
set arrow 20 from 0.44, 0.7967 to 0.9,0 nohead linestyle 20

set label '0.9' at 0.01, 0.1559 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.8' at 0.06, 0.2425 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.7' at 0.11, 0.3291 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.6' at 0.16, 0.4157 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.5' at 0.21, 0.5023 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.4' at 0.26, 0.5889 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.3' at 0.31, 0.6755 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.2' at 0.36, 0.7621 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60
set label '0.1' at 0.41, 0.8487 textcolor rgb C2 font "Arial, 9" rotate by -60

# y
set arrow 21 from 0.50, 0.866 to 0,0 nohead linestyle 3
set arrow 22 from 0.09,-0.0173 to 0.55, 0.779 nohead linestyle 30 
set arrow 23 from 0.19,-0.0173 to 0.60, 0.693 nohead linestyle 30
set arrow 24 from 0.29,-0.0173 to 0.65, 0.606 nohead linestyle 30
set arrow 25 from 0.39,-0.0173 to 0.70, 0.520 nohead linestyle 30
set arrow 26 from 0.49,-0.0173 to 0.75, 0.433 nohead linestyle 30
set arrow 27 from 0.59,-0.0173 to 0.80, 0.346 nohead linestyle 30
set arrow 28 from 0.69,-0.0173 to 0.85, 0.260 nohead linestyle 30
set arrow 29 from 0.79,-0.0173 to 0.90, 0.173 nohead linestyle 30
set arrow 30 from 0.89,-0.0173 to 0.95, 0.0866 nohead linestyle 30


set label '0.9' at 0.86, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.8' at 0.76, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.7' at 0.66, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.6' at 0.56, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.5' at 0.46, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.4' at 0.36, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.3' at 0.26, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.2' at 0.16, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60
set label '0.1' at 0.06, -0.0693 textcolor rgb C3 font "Arial, 9" rotate by 60

plot "Template_data.txt"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from my collection. It uses a loop to create the tics, tic labels and grid lines.
In this example, the range is from 0 to 100, but can easily be adjusted to 0 and 1.
Furthermore, it uses the functions `tx(a,b,c)` and `ty(a,b,c)` to map the `a,b,c` coordinates to `x,y` coordinates.
There is certainly room for optimizations and improvements.

**Code:**

```
### ternary plot
reset session
myTop = sqrt(0.75)      # top and ratio of triangle plot
set size ratio myTop
set angle degrees
unset tics
set border 0
set tmargin screen 0.92
set bmargin screen 0.12
unset clip points
set key noautotitle

set xrange[0:100]
set yrange[0:myTop*(100+1e-12)]   # otherwise point at top will not be displayed

# mapping of a,b,c coordinates to x,y coordinates
tx(a,b,c) = (a + b*cos(60))/(a+b+c)*100
ty(a,b,c) =      b*cos(30) /(a+b+c)*100

Color1 = "red"
Color2 = "web-green"
Color3 = "blue"

# triangle border
set arrow 1 from tx(0,0,1),ty(0,0,1) to tx(1,0,0),ty(1,0,0) nohead
set arrow 2 from tx(1,0,0),ty(1,0,0) to tx(0,1,0),ty(0,1,0) nohead
set arrow 3 from tx(0,1,0),ty(0,1,0) to tx(0,0,1),ty(0,0,1) nohead

# triangle axes labels
set label 11 "Material A / %" at tx(1,0,1),ty(1,0,1) offset 0,-2.5 center tc rgb Color1 font ",13"
set label 21 "Material B / %" at tx(1,1,0),ty(1,1,0) offset 10*cos(60) ,cos(30) rotate by -60 center tc rgb Color2 font ",13"
set label 31 "Material C / %" at tx(0,1,1),ty(0,1,1) offset 12*cos(120),cos(30) rotate by  60 center tc rgb Color3 font ",13"

# corner labels
set label 1 "A" at tx(1,0,0),ty(1,0,0) font ",14" center tc rgb Color1 offset  4,-1
set label 2 "B" at tx(0,1,0),ty(0,1,0) font ",14" center tc rgb Color2 offset  0,1.5
set label 3 "C" at tx(0,0,1),ty(0,0,1) font ",14" center tc rgb Color3 offset -4,-1

# define arrow styles
set style arrow 1 nohead lc rgb Color1 dt 3 lw 1.2
set style arrow 2 nohead lc rgb Color2 dt 3 lw 1.2
set style arrow 3 nohead lc rgb Color3 dt 3 lw 1.2

# create the tics, labels and grid in a loop
do for [i=0:100:10] {
    # axes tic labels
    set label i+100 at tx(i,0,100-i),ty(i,0,100-i) sprintf("%d",i) offset -1,-1 center tc rgb Color1 rotate by 0
    set label i+101 at tx(100-i,i,0),ty(100-i,i,0) sprintf("%d",i) offset  2,0  left   tc rgb Color2 rotate by 0
    set label i+102 at tx(0,100-i,i),ty(0,100-i,i) sprintf("%d",i) offset -1,1  right  tc rgb Color3 rotate by 0

    # axes tics
    set arrow i+100 from tx(i,0,100-i),ty(i,0,100-i) length 2 angle -120 nohead dt 1
    set arrow i+101 from tx(100-i,i,0),ty(100-i,i,0) length 2 angle    0 nohead dt 1
    set arrow i+102 from tx(0,100-i,i),ty(0,100-i,i) length 2 angle  120 nohead dt 1

    # grid
    set arrow i+103 from tx(i,0,100-i),ty(i,0,100-i) to tx(i,100-i,0),ty(i,100-i,0) as 1
    set arrow i+104 from tx(0,i,100-i),ty(100-i,i,0) to tx(100-i,i,0),ty(100-i,i,0) as 2 
    set arrow i+105 from tx(0,100-i,i),ty(0,100-i,i) to tx(100-i,0,i),ty(100-i,0,i) as 3 
}

$Data <<EOD
#a  b  c  color     label
 1  0  0  0xff0000  "A only"
 0  1  0  0x00c000  "B only"
 0  0  1  0x0000ff  "C only"
 1  1  1  0xff00ff  "A,B,C equal"
EOD

set style textbox opaque noborder
plot $Data u (tx($1,$2,$3)):(ty($1,$2,$3)):4 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb var,\
        '' u (tx($1,$2,$3)):(ty($1,$2,$3)):5 w labels boxed offset 4,1
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]